# Problems opening an excel Workbook, .Net Framework problem

Tags: excel, powerquery

The workbook in question contains queries from the Data, Get and Transform section, also known as PowerQuery. PowerQuery uses the .NET framework, hence it loads when you open a workbook which contains (or has contained) any PQ connections. I wish to share this workbook with other people but when they try to open the same they get this error and the excel keeps on loading. Im loading the query directly to Power Pivot to the Data Model.
[These is the error that shows to people when i share the excel workbook and they try opening it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW7BR.jpg)

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving.

Comment: Hi, already edited the comment and posted the picture of the problems that is showing to some people.

Comment: That just says 'Loading .NET framework'.. That is a normal step in the opening of excel.

Comment: I know, the problem is that this just keeps loading and the excel workbook never opens, and sometimes it even crashes the Excel.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know what's happening, with so little context, but the troubleshooting steps I would take are as follows:

1. Check the origin files was created with the same architecture ( x32 excel vs x64 excel ) as the deployment location. Upgrade the deployment location if necessary. Also check that they are the same version ( O365 vs Excel 2003 ).
2. Turn off refresh on open in the origin location, save and attempt to open on the deployment machine.
3. Attempt to connect to *recreate* the PowerQuery steps in a blank workbook in the deployment  machine. Can you even recreate the logic? Is it an unsupported function or strange connection loop?
4. Can the newly created file on the deployment machine, work on the origin machine?
5. Finally reinstall office everywhere. Check you have the same and correct .NET framework on both machines. Maybe reinstall?

Those steps should give you some idea of where your problem lies. Is it in the code, or is it the machine, or is it the software.